# Apache doesn't redirect react requests with more than 2 slashes in url correctly

Tags: apache, redirect, reactjs, react-router

I need to respond every react-app request with the same `js/bundle.js` file but do not do actual redirect - leave the url the same. Because after `bundle.js` returns - react-router will get any page it needs from this `bundle.js` file.

When in the url there is one "/" - reloading of the page `/welcome` or any else works fine.

But when i try to reload `/auth/login` (two slashes) it tries to find `bundle.js` from `auth/js/bundle.js` and gives an error.

I'm using

```
    RewriteEngine on
    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

But it doesn't help.
Here is my react-router

```
function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
    if (!localStorage.mazoomToken) {
        replace({
            pathname: '/auth/login',
            state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
        })
    }
}

function hasAuth(nextState, replace) {
    if (localStorage.mazoomToken) {
        replace({
            pathname: '/',
            state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
        })
    }
}

const router = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <Route path="/" onEnter={requireAuth} component={App}>
                <IndexRoute component={Events}/>
                <Route path="welcome" component={WelcomePage} onEnter={requireAuth}/>
                <Route path="contacts" component={Contacts} onEnter={requireAuth}/>
                <Route path="profile" component={Account} onEnter={requireAuth}/>
            </Route>

            <Route path="/auth/" component={Auth} onEnter={hasAuth}>
                <Route path="sign_up" component={SignUp} onEnter={hasAuth}/>
                <Route path="login" component={Login} onEnter={hasAuth}/>
                <Route path="forgot_pass" component={ForgotPassword} onEnter={hasAuth}/>
                <Route path="password/:token" component={NewPassword} onEnter={hasAuth}/>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
);
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in index.html - when linking script js/bundle.js I didn't put slash before js - /js/index.js.